# Auth Expiration Date

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

I am working on a credit card processing system for an eCommerce website. We do full amount authorization during checkout and settlement just before delivering the goods (7-14 days).

Question: Is there a way to get the "auth expiration date" as part of the authorization response from the issuer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can get an authorization but no expiration date is given with it. Typically it is 30 days but it doesn't have to be that long. But if you're charging within 14 days you should be fine as they are never shorter then that.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to check if my original auth is still valid?

Comment: @Charlie - Unfortunately the only way to know is to try to capture it.

Answer (score 1):

No. And in my experience frequently the card issuer only holds the authorization for **two** days (such as on debit cards). Credit cards can have longer hold periods (up to 30 days)

If you commonly find a delay between auth and capture like this, best practice is to perform a zero value auth (to check card details are valid only), then perform full authorization and capture just prior to dispatch (and within two days of each other)